# Is cloudfoundry uaa can be used as common oauth/openid server?

Tags: cloud-foundry

i found cloudfoundry uaa on github.

github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa

is it designed for cloudfoundry cloud services only or i can use it as oauth/openid server with my web application ?

Comment: cloundyfoundry? What is this? A google search shows no results.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa Wouldn't it be better to just email and ask the developers?

Comment: Here is the vcap_dev OSS site > https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UAA *is* designed to be generic and generally usable as an OAuth2 server and identity management solution.  It's use and current home in Cloud Foundry could be seen as validation that it works in production, but it is very much supposed to be used by others. Feedback on the google list would be great, but if you prefer to ask questions, stackoverflow works too (the CF support team monitors the cloudfoundry keyword).

Comment: and it does support OpenID Connect(OIDC) and OIDC tokens